# Nodejs post request variable scope issue

Tags: node.js, variables, post, scope, global-variables

I'm somewhat new to Nodejs.
In the following code I'm getting data from an API.

```
request.post({ url:endpoint, form: requestParams }, function (err, response, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error = " + err);
    }
    else {
        let parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
        if (parsedBody.error_description) {
            console.log("Error = " + parsedBody.error_description);
        }
        else {
            // testFunc(AccessToken);
            test = "Success!";
            testFunc(test);
        }
    }
});

function testFunc(success){
    Token = success;
    console.log(Token);
}

// this code gives the error "Token is not defined" \/
console.log(Token);
```

in the post request i make the variable "test". I want to be able to use this as a global variable so i can use it in a get request.

When i `console.log()` "Token" in the "testFunc" it will log it correctly.
But when i `console.log()` outside the function it gives the error `Token is not defined`.

How can i get the "Token" or the "test" variable to be global so i can use it in another get request?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your request.post is running asynchronous 
you can use request-promise lib

```
const request = require("request-promise");
```

and change to

```
var result = await request(options);
```

or for more knowledge read this article 
https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/

Answer (score 1):

your `Token` is local variable on the `testFunc`

```
function testFunc(success){
    Token = success;
    console.log(Token);
}
```

try to define the `Token` as the global variable
you can put after all import require(...) or above the `request.post`

```
let Token; //this is global declared variable
```

and also your `console.log` cannot be just like your code

as your question `I want to be able to use this as a global variable so i can use it in a get request.`

so you need to put your `console.log` inside the `request.get`

something like

```
request.get('xxxxxx', , function(err) {
    console.log("Token is " , Token);
});
```

Comment: Making the variable global didn't work for me. I added the `let Token;` above the `request.post` but the `console.log(Token)` returns a `undefined`.
The reason i didn't put the console.log() in the `request.get` already is just to test, since i can't access the variable outside the `request.post` i figured that i also can't access it inside the `request.get`

Comment: your `request.post` is running asynchronous. it mean even the `Token` is not assigned with value, your console.log at the below is already executed, thats why you get undefined